# Java - TableModelListener stops working after table content changes

Tags: java, jtable, listener

I am trying to listen to two linked tables using one TableModelListener each. My first table changes the content of the second table while the second table changes the content of a text box. However, after changing the table content of the second table the TableModelListener of the second table stops registering the event.

I cannot get this code to work. Could anyone please point me into the right direction?

```
package tablelistenertest;


import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;

public class TableListenerTest extends JPanel  { 
    private javax.swing.JTable table1;
    private javax.swing.JTable table2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField text1;

    public TableListenerTest() {

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        table1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        table1.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table1.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        add(new JScrollPane(table1));

        table2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        table2.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table2.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        add(new JScrollPane(table2));

        text1 = new javax.swing.JTextField("", 40);
        text1.setEditable(false);
        add(new JScrollPane(text1));

        String[] columnNames = {
            "Column 1",
            "Column 2",
            "Column 3"
        };

        Object[][] data = {
             {new Boolean(true), "1", "a" },
             {new Boolean(false), "2", "b"},
         };

         Object[][] data2 = {
             {new Boolean(false), "3", "c"},
             {new Boolean(false), "4", "d"}
         };

         table1.setModel( new MyTableModel( columnNames, data ) );
         table2.setModel( new MyTableModel( columnNames, data2 ) );
         text1.setText("test");

         table1.getModel().addTableModelListener( new TableModelListener() {
             @Override
             public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) {
                 if( evt.getColumn() == 0 && evt.getFirstRow() > -1 ){
                     if( (Boolean) table1.getValueAt(0, 0) && !(Boolean) table1.getValueAt(1, 0) ){
                         Object[][] data2 = {                            
                             {new Boolean(true), "5", "e" },
                             {new Boolean(false), "6", "f"}
                         };
                         table2.setModel( new MyTableModel( columnNames, data2 ) );                 
                     }
                     else if( !(Boolean) table1.getValueAt(0, 0) && (Boolean) table1.getValueAt(1, 0) ){
                         Object[][] data2 = {                            
                             {new Boolean(true), "7", "g" },
                             {new Boolean(false), "8", "h"}
                         };
                         table2.setModel( new MyTableModel( columnNames, data2 ) );                 
                     }
                     else if( (Boolean) table1.getValueAt(0, 0) && (Boolean) table1.getValueAt(1, 0) ){
                         Object[][] data2 = {                            
                             {new Boolean(true), "9", "i" },
                             {new Boolean(false), "10", "j"}
                         };
                         table2.setModel( new MyTableModel( columnNames, data2 ) );                 
                     }
                     else{
                         Object[][] data2 = {                            
                             {new Boolean(true), "11", "k" },
                             {new Boolean(false), "12", "l"}
                         };
                         table2.setModel( new MyTableModel( columnNames, data2 ) );                 
                     }  
                 }
             }
         } );

         table2.getModel().addTableModelListener( new TableModelListener() {
             @Override
             public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) {
                 if( evt.getColumn() == 0 && evt.getFirstRow() > -1 ){
                     if( (Boolean) table2.getValueAt(0, 0) && !(Boolean) table2.getValueAt(1, 0) ){
                         text1.setText("test1");                 
                     }
                     else if( !(Boolean) table2.getValueAt(0, 0) && (Boolean) table2.getValueAt(1, 0) ){
                         text1.setText("test2");                 
                     }
                     else if( (Boolean) table2.getValueAt(0, 0) && (Boolean) table2.getValueAt(1, 0) ){
                         text1.setText("test3");                 
                     }
                     else{
                         text1.setText("test4");                 
                     }
                 }
             }
         } );
     }

     class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

         private String[] columnNames;
         private Object[][] data;

         public MyTableModel(String[] columnNames, Object[][] data) {
             this.columnNames = columnNames;
             this.data = data;
         }        

         @Override
         public int getColumnCount() {
             return columnNames.length;
         }

         @Override
         public int getRowCount() {
             return data.length;
         }

         @Override
         public String getColumnName(int col) {
             return columnNames[col];
         }

         @Override
         public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
             return data[row][col];
         }

         @Override
         public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
             return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
         }

         @Override
         public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
             return col == 0;
         }

         @Override
         public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
             data[row][col] = value;
             fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
         } 
     }


     private static void createAndShowGUI() {

         UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE); 

         JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableListenerTest");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         TableListenerTest newContentPane = new TableListenerTest();
         newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
         frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

         frame.pack();
         frame.setVisible(true);
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 createAndShowGUI();
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

Comment: You register a `TableModelListener` to the first model you set, but later you replace the model of the table with another one , which has no `TableModelListener` .

Comment: sorry, not sure what that means. Which model do you mean? I thought I add a TableModelListener to each table i.e. table1.getModel().add... and the same for table2.

Comment: No, `table1.getModel().add` will only add a listener to the CURRENT model of the table, not to possible future models .

Comment: Great, thanks! I get it now! Copying the TableModelListener for table2 in the TableModelListener code for table1 fixes it.

Comment: @Christian: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188).